# swagger-ui doesn't list any of the controllers endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add Swagger to a very simple hello word Spring-Boot project.

I'm following this tutorial :

https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

this is my SwaggerConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig{

@Bean
public Docket greetingApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.swaggerready"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(metaData());

}

private ApiInfo metaData() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Spring Boot REST API")
            .description("\"Spring Boot REST API for greeting people\"")
            .version("1.0.0")
            .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
            .build();
}


}
```

However, the results I have running it is only the first page without any information. 
[image]

This is the repository if someone wants to see the full code.
https://github.com/ThadeuFerreira/SpringMicro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class SwaggerConfig you need to change line:

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.swaggerready"))
```

To:

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.SpringMicro"))
```